# My site is acting weird in chrome, but works fine with Firefox/Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I just uploaded my portfolio site, now everything was working fine till I opened the site in Chrome. The navigation bar is positioned weirdly and the bullets are showing up suddenly, while this is not the case in other browsers.

Is there a quick fix or something that's very common that could cause this problem?

This picture is the site in Firefox:

[image: This is the page on Firefox]

This picture is the site in Chrome:

[image: This is the page on chrome]

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) Problems need to be captured in the question itself here, so that they remain reproducible for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you clean your **Cache** in Google Chrome?
With

> Shift + F5

You can clean your Cache and reload the Page.

In my case it looks the same in Google chrome as in Firefox

Comment: Lol your a champ! Never knew this was a thing, I kept re-uploading my site but nothing changed. It works now!

Comment: Yes if something is happen again, you can check withing the developer console if your code is the same as you have write. If not, you know its a caching problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks exactly the same for me in Chrome and Firefox. You can maybe try clearing the cache in chrome by using Shift + F5.

Do check if your browser is resized or if the default scale of the document is not 1. By the way, the UI looks good.